# Javascript - Load content, callback and loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my 'getContent' functions which takes a URL:

```
function getContent(url, callback) {
    var request = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
    request.set_url(url);
    request.set_httpVerb("GET");
    var del = Function.createCallback(getContentResults, callback);
    request.add_completed(del);
    request.invoke();
}
```

What I'd like to do is display a loading image when this is called and then hide it when the callback is complete?

Can any suggest antying?

Comment: I wonder in what kind of Javascript framework or lib is your code written?

Comment: I don't see how jQuery comes into this ? lol if you are, or are you looking for jquery equivalent

Comment: jQuery equivalent would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery .load() function to load your HTML, then use the .ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() event handlers to show and hide the loading animation.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loadlink").click( function() {
        $("#container").load( "load.htm" );
    });

    $("#loadlink").ajaxStart( function() {
        console.log("start");
    });

    $("#loadlink").ajaxStop( function() {
        console.log("stop");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selector').html('<img src="loading.gif" />').ajax({
   URL: 'myurl',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType:'html',
   success:function (data){
        console.log('This has changed');
        // data is your html returned/response
   },
   error: function (){
        //this handles errors such as 404,500, etc...
   }
});
```

**Whats happening?**

```
$('#selector')//is where the result would be shown this instance <div id="selector">
    .html('<img src="loading.gif" />')// adds an image to <div id="selector"><img src="loading" /></div>
    .ajax();//well its the ajax call to get the page data
```

**for more information**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/